# ngSwitch does not work with string

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-switch

I'm trying to get ngSwitch to dynamically show and hide component, however ngSwitch does not seem to be working.

I've created a simplifed version of this issue with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FAcPZ5AEuXFSW5bbcfY4?p=preview)

This is the component Html:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="componentType">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="input">
    <div>Rendered</div>
    <ion-item [hidden]="editOptions.isEditing">
      <ion-note color="primary">{{label}}</ion-note>
      <ion-note class="inline-edit"> {{value}}&nbsp;</ion-note>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item [hidden]="!editOptions.isEditing">
      <ion-label color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="value" [required]="required" [type]="type" [name]="value"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="Lama"><div>Rendered</div></div>
</div>
```

This is my TypeScript file:

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    ElementRef,
    ViewChild,
    Renderer,
    forwardRef,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { EditOptions } from '../../../models/editOptions';

const INLINE_EDIT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InlineEditComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'inline-edit',
  templateUrl: 'inline-edit.html',
  providers: [INLINE_EDIT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
})
export class InlineEditComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

    @ViewChild('inlineEditControl') inlineEditControl: ElementRef;
    @Input() label: string = '';
    @Input() type: string = 'text';
    @Input() componentType: string = 'input';
    @Input() required: boolean = false;
    @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
    @Input() editOptions: EditOptions;
    private _value: string = '';
    private preValue: string = '';
    public onChange: any = Function.prototype;
    public onTouched: any = Function.prototype;

    get value(): any {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this._value) {
            this._value = v;
            this.onChange(v);
        }
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    constructor(element: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

The weird thing is my switch is looking for the value 'input' and even though it's defined in the case it still generated null binding

[image]

Comment: Try `*ngSwitchCase="'Lama'"`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should have it inside **`''`**

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'input''>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'Lama'"><div>Rendered</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I just realized this a second ago I wish it would warn me

Comment: @johnny5 The problem is it doesn't know whether you meant to use a string literal, or whether you meant to use a variable but forgot to define it.

Comment: Yeah, I wish it would give me a warning that I'm using an undefined variable